# Algebraic Equation?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$$Ve^{i\theta} = We^{i\phi}$$

where, $V$ and $W$ are some real constants. From this my book concludes: $\theta = \phi$. How does it conclude this? I don't see why its valid to just equate the exponent parts (which I think my book does).

Comment: $V,W$ are real ?

Comment: Also theta and phi?

Comment: $V,W$ are positive ?

Comment: @Amr $V,W,\theta, \phi$ are all real.

Comment: Also, are you reading an engineering / physics book ?

Comment: I mean that is incorrect as stated so maybe there is more context here.

Comment: Maybe V,W are positive and theta and phi are angles not real numbers.

Comment: @Seth Sorry, theta and pi are angles. I though angles *were* real numbers.

Comment: as angles $0=2\pi$ but not as real numbers

Comment: @Amr Yes, it's a book on circuit analysis.

Comment: @Amr I guessed that you were studying circuit analysis btw .

Comment: @Amr Haha, nice ;)

Comment: @Amr What gave it away? I used $i$ instead of $j$ and changed most of the constants in the original equation.

Comment: I wrote an answer.  I'm guessing that this is what the book was using.  It is necessary to assume $V$ and $W$ are positive here.

Comment: @dfg sloppy reasoning is the norm in all engineering/physics classes I have taken so far (I am a mechanical engineering student). This is how I guessed

Comment: @Amr that's why I switched from physics to math (lol)

Comment: @Amr That's disappointing. I noticed that too, and was hoping it would improve in later years. I guess not.

Comment: @dfg It will get much worse

Comment: @Seth Good move. You can turn back to physics once you have the necessary mathematical background. At my university, physics students study physics that contains advanced mathematics without learning the necessary mathematics (and thus I dont they understand what they learn). For example they learn about homeomorphisms and manifolds in the middle of a physics course without learning what a topology is, read physics that discusses lie groups without studying algebra

Comment: @Amr yeah I've seen what you are talking about firsthand.  I'm getting a PhD in math now so I'm not going back.  No regrets =)

Answer (score 1):

If $R>0$ and $\theta\in \mathbb{R}$ then the complex number $Re^{i\theta}$ has magnitude $R$ and angle $\theta$.  So if $V>0$ and $W>0$ and $Ve^{i\theta}=We^{i\phi}$ then the magnitudes and angles are equal.  Hence $V = W$ and $\theta = \phi +2\pi k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

The conclusion is false anyways, but I'll show you how to deduce something close to what you really need.

$$Ve^{i\theta}=We^{i\phi}$$
$$|Ve^{i\theta}|=|We^{i\phi}|$$
$$|V||e^{i\theta}|=|W||e^{i\phi}|$$

Since $|e^{i\gamma}|=1$ for every $\gamma$, therefore:

$$|V|=|W|$$

Case 1: $V,W>0$ I think this is the case in your book, but they don't stress the importance that this is the case for their argument because their argument is sloppy.

In this case $V=|V|=|W|=W$, therefore you can divide in your original equation by $V$. To get $e^{i\theta}=e^{i\phi}$. For circuit analysis purposes, all you would need to know is this. Which is equivalent to $\frac{\theta-\phi}{2\pi}$ is an integer (and this is all what you really need to know when working with impedances). but NOT $\theta=\phi$.

Case 2: $V,W=0$

Then there is no relation between $\theta,\pi$

Case 3: $V,W$ are non-zero reals

Then one can conclude that $\frac{\theta-\phi}{\pi}$ is an integer by the method I used earlier. I'll leave this to you

Comment: You will experience sloppy reasoning in other engineering/physics courses. Most of the times, the sloppiness level will be much higher than this !!

Answer (score 0):

You have that $$
  e^{i\alpha} = \cos \alpha + i\sin\alpha \quad\text{and}\quad |e^{i\alpha}| = \sqrt{(\cos\alpha)^2 + (\sin\alpha)^2} = 1\text{,}
$$

i.e. $e^{i\alpha}$ always is a point on the unit circle, at angle $\alpha$ away counter-clockwise from $+1$.

If $V,W$ are both positive real numbers, then the only way for $$
  Ve^{i\theta} = We^{i\phi}
$$
to hold is thus that $$
  V = W \quad\text{ and }\quad e^{i\theta} = e^{i\phi} \text{.}
$$
That does *not* implies that $\theta = \phi$, though. $\alpha \to e^{i\alpha}$ is *not* an injective function, because $$
  e^{i\alpha} = e^{i\alpha + i2\pi n} \quad\text{for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.}
$$
But what you *can* say is that $Ve^{i\theta} = We^{i\phi}$ implies  $$
  V = W \quad\text{ and }\quad \theta - \phi = 2\pi n \text{ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.}
$$
In your book, $\theta$ and $\phi$ are probably supposed to be *angles*, and thus are either assumed lie within the interval $[0,2\pi)$ or it is implicitly assumed that two angles are equal if their difference is a multiple of $2\pi$. With either of this additional prerequisits, you *can* indeed conclude that $\theta = \phi$.